# How to add hook into portlet in liferay?

Tags: java, liferay

I have made a struts action hook and want to add it to the portlet. I tried several things like I made first a portlet plugin project and then tried to add hook into it by right clicking on the portlet project and clicking on **New->Liferay** Hook Configuration but there is no option of struts action hook there.

So I decided to make hook first. I am now ready with the hook and need to add it to the portlet.

How can I achieve it? Is there any way to add struts action hook to the portlet?

Comment: The hook is available globally in liferay all portlets including those core portal portlets will use it if required...You have to be more specific on what you need the hook to do for your portlet

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix struts path of the portlet in which you want to add struts action. You can find struts path for Liferay OOTB portlets in /ROOT/WEB-INF/liferay-portlet.xml.

Example:

Consider you want to add new struts action to message boards portlet. you have to write `struts-action-path` in liferay-hook.xml as follow :

`<struts-action-path>/message_boards/new_struts_action</struts-action-path>`

HTH